# Output Stream write not returning in Android

Tags: android, file-upload, httpurlconnection

I am uploading a file to server using the HttpsURLConnection class in Android. I am using PUT method. In normal circumstances it is working fine, but when I am attempting to write a file to the folder in a server, which does not have write permissions,  the write method should fail and then when I use getResponseCode() I should recieve a 403 Forbidden response from the server.  I have to use the 403 response to show a "No Permissions" message to the user.

Now, when the file size that I upload is less than the buffer size (16K), the write method returns and the getResponseCode returns 403. However, when the file size is bigger (which is usually the case), the program stucks in the write method and thus does not reach the getResponseCode  at all. This is happening in all Android devices including the simulator.

Here is the code snippet:

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = getSSLChannel();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
connection.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(size);
connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();


    try{
        int count =0;       
        long progress = 0;
        byte[] chunkData = new byte[16384];
        long fileSize = localFile.getLocalFileSize();
        bis = getSourceBufferedStream();

        while (((nRead = bis.read(chunkData)) != -1)) {
            if(nRead < chunkData.length){
            byte[] newBytes = Arrays.copyOf(chunkData, nRead);
            out.write(newBytes, 0, nRead);
            count++;
            }else{
                out.write(chunkData, 0, nRead);
                count++;
            }
        }

        out.flush();
    }finally{
        if(out != null){
            try {
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    int resCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Res Code :" + resCode);
}
```

I have put a debug pointer in the finally block. But the app never enters the finally block.

Some points:
1. The server does not support multipart upload.
2. There is no Separate web service to find out, if the folder has write permissions on the server.
3. In iOS this works fine. I am able to receive 403.
4. I have tried with Fiddler, which also gives me a 403.
5. Also, in fast networks (if the server is located in the local wifi domain), I am able to get 403 sometimes.

What am I doing wrong ? Please help !

Thanks.

Comment: Does this occur on Android 4.4, or on earlier versions, or both?

Comment: This occurs on all versions including 4.4

Comment: Please could anyone reply ? Thanks.

Comment: Any comments by anyone ? Am still stuck with this.

Comment: @Sougata did you ever figure out this issue?

Comment: Not yet. I guess we are not getting a 100-continue response code from the server, when writting a file using PUT